# Can I sell a blog content database in a Creative Commons Attribution license?

Tags: creative-commons

I have a blog online under a Creative Commons Attribution license.
I would like to monetize it by offering monthly content database of the blog content for sale to developers at a low price of 1 USD.  This will enable developers to build mobile and iPAD apps which have offline content.

Is this legal under the Creative Commons Attribution license?

Answer (score 4):

You can sell any content created by you, regardless of the copyright license (as long as you have not sold or given the rights away).

Be aware that under a Creative Commons Attribution license, so can any one else.  You might be looking for a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial license.

Attribution license: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

Attribution-NonCommercial license: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/